# Moto seems to stop mocking after upgrading boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, moto

I have upgraded boto3 from `boto3==1.7.48 to 1.13.11`, and this has broken all of my tests that use Moto. It looks like (worryingly) the mock has stopped working altogether and is trying to actually access s3, here is an example test function that was previously working:

```
def upload_video(self, video):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    for media_key in video.upload_media_keys:
        s3.upload_file(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "assets/test.mp4"
            ),
            settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            media_key,
        )
```

But it now gives this error

```
  File "{path}", line 52, in upload_video
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
  File "{path}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "{path}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the list of upgrades:

Before:

```
boto3 == 1.7.48
botocore == 1.10.84
moto == 1.3.6
```

After:

```
boto3==1.13.11
botocore==1.16.11 
moto==1.3.14
```

Comment: There's an issue explaining the thing in more detail at `moto`'s GitHub - https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/3292.

Answer (score 16):

I have no idea what changed, but I also ran into this. Here's my workaround:

Previously I had:

```py
    conn = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="ca-central-1")
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket=os.environ["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
```

but I changed the region to `us-east-1` and everything worked

```py
    conn = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket=os.environ["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
```

Since this is just a fake bucket for testing, I see no harm in using a different region if it makes things work

Comment: Saved the day!!

Comment: Rather use the code example here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html as doing the above will make your tests semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the region in your tests which you do by using LocationConstraint.

I'm using the following in my code. Of course the s3 is mocked using moto.

```
location = {'LocationConstraint': "eu-central-1"}
s3.create_bucket(Bucket="somebucket", CreateBucketConfiguration=location)
```

The s3 mock, written with pytest.

```
from moto import mock_s3

@pytest.fixture
def s3(aws_credentials):
    with mock_s3():
        conn = boto3.client("s3", region_name="eu-central-1")
        yield conn
```

Comment: I think this is actually the more correct answer. This is essentially the example code given in the link in the accepted answers comments.